# Java Xml caching

Tags: java, xml, caching, xml-parsing

Is there a efficient way to cache all the nodes of an xml file in Java?

For example can I have a map with xpath as key and the value corresponding to that xpath in the xml as the value.

Or if there is any other way of doing it?

Comment: Can you please give an example of your xml ?

Comment: Hi @urag, I am hoping it to be generic... So any xml can go